# sql server shrink a >5 varchar string to fit a varchar(4)

Tags: sql, function, truncate, shrink

I'm a total newbye to SQL functions, this is my first question after searching a lot about this topic.

I'm trying to select a list of values which are varchar (8) and transform them into varchar (4)
To do this i would need to truncate the value at the third position and append a char which varies from 1 to 9, then restarts from 1

e.g PATOL, PATOLB , PATOLC should become PAT1, PAT2, PAT3 and so on

I've found on the web a piece of code which i'm trying to adapt, but i'm having troubles with the increment of the counter

please be patient for the mistakes, and for the non-elegant form, this is my first attempt of coding since my Commodore 64 BASIC in the 80's

here's my function:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER function [dbo].[f_To4char] (@value varchar(10))
RETURNS varchar(4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @seq varchar(9)
    DECLARE @digit char (1)
    DECLARE @3car varchar(3)
    DECLARE @result varchar(4)
    DECLARE @count int

SET @seq = '123456789'
SET @count = 1

    IF len(@value)<=4
    return @value
else

BEGIN   
WHILE (@count <=9)

        BEGIN
        SET @digit = SUBSTRING(@seq,@count,1)
        SET @count = @count+1
        SET @3car = substring (@value,1,3)
        SET @result = @3car+@digit
        END
END
RETURN @result

END
```

It correctly return values untouched if they are <=4 chars long, and correctly truncates longer values to 3 chars, but always appends the same char instead of cycling from 1 to 9.

Can You please help me to make it work?
Thank You

**EDIT (2016-10-12)**
Thanks for the answer and comments
Meanwhile i've tried the following, but nothing to do: it always returns 1 as appended char

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

go

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_To4char](@value VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS varchar(4)
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @digit char(1);
        DECLARE @count smallint;
        DECLARE @3car VARCHAR(3);
        DECLARE @shrunk varchar(4);
        DECLARE @result VARCHAR(4);

set @count=1 ;

        IF LEN(@value) <= 4
           RETURN @value;
        ELSE



        BEGIN

            begin
             if @count=1 
             set @digit = '1';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end

            begin
             if @count=2 
             set @digit = '2';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end

            begin
             if @count=3 
             set @digit = '3';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end

            begin
             if @count=4 
             set @digit = '4';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end         

            begin
             if @count=5 
             set @digit = '5';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end

            begin
             if @count=6 
             set @digit = '6';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end

            begin
             if @count=6 
             set @digit = '6';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end

            begin
             if @count=7 
             set @digit = '7';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end

            begin
             if @count=8 
             set @digit = '8';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end

            begin
             if @count=9 
             set @digit = '9';
             SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
             SET @shrunk = @3car + @digit;
             set @count=@count+1    
             RETURN @shrunk;    
            end         




if @count=10 set @count=1



        END;
      return @shrunk
 END;
```

Comment: In what way should it cycle 1 - 9? It doesn't have any knowledge of what was appended to previous strings?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_To4char](@value VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(4)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @seq VARCHAR(9);
        DECLARE @digit CHAR(1);
        DECLARE @3car VARCHAR(3);
        DECLARE @result VARCHAR(4);
        IF LEN(@value) <= 4
           RETURN @value;
        ELSE
           BEGIN
              SET @digit = LEN(@value) - 4; --<--this may have to be 3 rather than 4 depending on what you want the suffix to be.
              SET @3car = SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 3);
              SET @result = @3car + @digit;
           END;
        RETURN @result;
    END;
```

Avoid using loops anywhere you can. They cause slowdown performance.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be correct, inputs of PATOLA and PATOLB will return the same output?

Comment: what should it return? The length of the characters for PATOLA and PATOLB are the same so they should return the same from what I understand but I may have misunderstood.

Comment: Per his question PATOLA should return PAT2 and PATOLB should return PAT3. I don't think it's possible without a stored procedure or making some huge assumptions regarding the inputs.

Comment: Agree. without having a table or having the business rules hard coded in the function that's not possible.

Comment: actually I need to convert longer strings (more than 4000 in a couple of table) to varchar(4) strings. e.g the original

Comment: e.g. the orignal values LONG, LONGER, LONGEST, VERYLONG should become LONG (4 char unchanged), LON1, LON2, VER3. When the last digit reaches 9 it should restart from 1, always, independently from the first 3 chars; meanwhile, i assume that the first part of the string has a different value, should duplicates arise from the shrinking (more than 9 values starting with the same 3 chars) I would deal with  them manually, hopefully they will not be too much, or, anyway, better than treat them all manually exporting and cutting into excel or some other processor.